# Learning AI, Machine Learning, Deep Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am a recent college graduate with a bachelors in computer engineering. I am very interested in deep learning however someone had mentioned to me that I should learn machine learning before I learn deep learning. Is that true ? And if so which online course would you recommend I start at ?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is entirely based on opinion. However, I would suggest Andrew Ng's Stanford course. It is a very good start. Then you should look into the algorithms that further interest you through tutorials or academic papers.

Answer (score 1):

Bascially this is true. Deep Learning is kind of like stacking your machine learning algorithms on top of each other. Have a look [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/7qru88/d_differences_between_ml_ds_and_ai_my_attempt_at/) and the associated picture.